# Attach Certificate to SOAP Client. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, x509certificate2

I was given a wsdl file (the first time using this type of software) and imported it into my project. I created a client from that wsdl reference and am attempting to attach a certificate to the client. I can confirm the certificate is being set in the code, however when I attempt to make my request I get an exception because the request is not being sent with a certificate.

```
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (obj, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
            MyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(myEndpoint));

            try
            {

                client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, certThumbprintString);
                client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerTrust;


                var response = await client.sendRequest(XMLData);

            }
```

In sharkwire it also says I am missing certs (view picture). How can the certificate be set in the C# but not be sent in the request? Is there something wrong with my code? Is it the certificate? Again this is all totally new to me so anything helps. Thanks in advance!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eirgF.png)

I have tried changing the bindings, a different certificate, threw in a ton of logging with all the same exception "Rejected by policy".